Travel on H1b for business purposes
I have valid H1b visa stamped, but relocated to my home country for personal reasons, yet still working for the same company.
Can I travel to US for business reasons on existing H1b Visa?

Are you really working for the same company, or are you working for a local branch of the company that is technically a separate legal entity?  If so, you don't have a US employer, don't have a valid petition, and can't enter in H-1B status.

Generally no. You need a visa which is appropriate to the visit. As a practical matter, you may be able to get through, but it will involve misrepresentation of the purpose of your visit to the CBP officer which is technically an immigration violation and grounds for revoking your visa.
For regular business visits (meetings and such) you should have a B1 visa.
If you're going back to being employed by the US employer as per the approved I-129 then yes, by all means, you can reuse the visa as long as it is still valid.

"grounds for revoking your visa": and worse; it would expose the traveler to a possible finding of inadmissibility for misrepresentation, which would mean no future visas (without obtaining a waiver).
